# How to remove java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException while using Future Interface

Tags: java, multithreading, futuretask

I have a controller in which I am using future interface and creating 5 threads in threadpool. This controller is called by an ajax call. When I call this controller the first time it runs fine but if I make the request again it shows the exception below.

```
  java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@1cbbac9 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@53ee53[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 5]
```

I am posting code how I am calling the tasks.

```
  private static final ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    FactorialCalculator task1 = new FactorialCalculator("A"); 
    FactorialCalculator task2 = new FactorialCalculator("B"); 
    FactorialCalculator task3= new FactorialCalculator("C"); 
    FactorialCalculator task4 = new FactorialCalculator("D"); 
    FactorialCalculator task5= new FactorialCalculator("E"); 
    System.out.println("Submitting Task ..."); 
    Future future1 = threadpool.submit(task1); 
    Future future2 = threadpool.submit(task2); 
    Future future3 = threadpool.submit(task3); 
    Future future4 = threadpool.submit(task4); 
    Future future5 = threadpool.submit(task5);  
    System.out.println("Task is submitted");
```

In first request it is running all tasks- A,B,C,D and E but when I make request again it prints submitting tasks but doesn't print Task is submitted. Can someone help out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Do happen to shut the executor down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't mentioned specifically which version of Java you're using, but I suspect the relevant classes haven't changed much.  The `ThreadPoolExecutor` will throw that exception from it's `execute` method in two cases, both of which rely on the executor's state being `SHUTDOWN`.

So I am fairly confident that the executor is rejecting your task submissions because it is being shut down at some point.  I notice your code is not telling the whole story, as it looks like the executor is a class field that might be referenced by other methods.  Check whether you're calling shutdown anywhere else.  (Note that the executor will be shut down by its finalizer; though in the block of code you've posted there's no way it will be eligible for garbage collection as it's a final field.)

---

As a footnote, whenever you're having trouble with code it's useful to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  The code you've posted doesn't compile, but after fixing this, [it runs successfully](http://ideone.com/tXoEgF).  Are you able to fork my Ideone script and reproduce your problem?

Comment: Note that when you scroll the exception’s message of the question horizontally, you can see from the executor’s `toString()` output that its state is indeed `Terminated`…